# Change User-agent in UIWebView (IOS 5)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, user-agent

What I have done so far:I use the code below to change User-Agent in UIWebView in the project.

```
NSDictionary *userAgentReplacement = [[NSDictionary alloc]           initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgent, @"UserAgent",nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userAgentReplacement];
```

Problem:I have this code working, however when I call the function again, to change the UserAgent to something else, UIWebView's do not update. In order to successfully update the UserAgent I need to remove/release the UIWebView and alloc/show it again, but it causes the UIWebView to lose all history. Is there any way to update the UserAgent without having to create a new UIWebView in order to have it take effect?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using NSUserDefaults I assume that you're setting them in

```
application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

The alternative that I've previously used is

```
NSMutableURLRequest*request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURL]];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

You can also use the UIWebView Delegate to capture the last loaded state of the webview using a NSString variable

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    currentConfig=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML];
}
```

And then reload the webView using

```
[webView loadHTMLString:currentConfig baseURL:yourURL];
```